# what does EXC BAD ACCESS MEAN? What does it mean in reference to my code?

Tags: linked-list

What does my error mean? How can I fix it?

See here for a photo of the error when I try to run the program ...

http://postimg.org/image/horh6d26j/

My program is attempting to remove the last element of a double linked list and insert it at the front

I am only trying to execute the backToFront function.
The activity is a past prac exam at my university from 2011(?)
I am trying to complete it in preparation for my prac exam -- which is in two days 
(aaahhhhhhh!!!!!!)

```
/*

 *  backToFront.c

 *  comp1917 pracExam #2 2011s1 UNSW

 *

 * Author: WRITE YOUR NAME HERE

 * Date: 21 June 2011

 * License: Public Domain

 */



// Implement the backToFront function below

// so that it moves the last node in a non-empty linked list

// of nodes to be the first node in the list, leaving the

// relative position of all the other nodes unchanged.



// You may assume the input list contains at least one node.

//

// Your function should do the moving by changing pointers

// in the nodes and list structs, (don't use malloc or make

// any new nodes)

//

// Your function should return the new list.

//

// You need to pass the tests in testBackToFront.c

//

// Compile and run the tests using

// gcc -Wall -Werror -O -o tester backtToFront.c testBackToFront.c

// ./tester

//

// When a test fails look in the testBackToFront.c file to see

// what the test was testing.  There are 3 tests in that file.

//

// Once you have passed all the tests you have finished.



#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <assert.h>

#include "backToFront.h"



list backToFront (list items) {

assert (items.first != NULL);

nodePtr current = items.first;   
nodePtr previous = NULL;

while (current != NULL){
    previous = current;
    current = current->rest;
}

current->rest = items.first;
items.first = current;
previous->rest = NULL;




return items;

}

/*

 *  backToFront.h

 *  pracExam 2011

 *

 *  Created by Richard Buckland on 26/07/09.

 *  Modified by David Collien on 20/06/11.

 *  Copyright 2011. All rights reserved.

 *

 */



// DO NOT ALTER OR SUBMIT THIS FILE

// we will use our own copy when marking



typedef struct _node *nodePtr;



typedef struct _list {

    nodePtr first;

} list;



// For le sorution, add /samplesolutions at the end of your url

typedef struct _node {

    int      value;

    nodePtr  rest;

} node;



// given a node (*item) and a list of nodes (items)

// this function takes the last node of the list

// and moves it to be the first node in the list.

//

// the function returns the altered list.

//

// (note that the function does not create new nodes

// or change the value field of existing nodes.)

list backToFront (list items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely out of bounds (no item at that index). Make sure the array isn't null

Comment: how do I do that?
I already have assert (items.first != NULL);
what else should i test?